# Facebook PHP SDK & Codeigniter: Unable to load config

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk

my config/facebook.php

```
$config['appId']        = 'XXXXX';
$config['secret']       = 'XXXX';
$config['fb_access_token'] = 'XXXXXX';
```

my controller:

```
$this->load->library('Facebook');  
echo $this->config->item('fb_access_token');
```

Outputs nothing for the the token? yet I know the library is loading as I can call getAppID ok. It just doesn't seem to be loading this config file.

Also tried this from the controller:

```
$this->config->load("facebook",TRUE);
$config = $this->config->item('facebook');
$this->load->library('facebook', $config);
```

Comment: Have you try with auto loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to load the library:

```
$this->config->load('facebook');
$config = array(
               'appId' => $this->config->item('appId'),
               'secret' => $this->config->item('secret'),
);
$this->load->library('facebook', $config);
```

You can set the access token only afterwards:

```
$this->facebook->setAccessToken($this->config->item('fb_access_token'));
```

Comment: IF I'm going to be making calls throughout my app to the Facebook library, should I create a wrapper of some sort to make this loading a bit quicker/less code?

Comment: @Quad6 You can set it in the constructor of the controller to make it available to all functions.